# Hide prices on home page of featured products

Tags: wordpress, widget, woocommerce, wordpress-featured-image

I'm using WooCommerce and very new to WordPress. I have displayed the featured products on Home Page with default featured products widgets. Now I want to hide the prices and product name only from Home Page.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code or query you are using to fetch the featured properties

Answer (score 0):

is_home() function checks if the page is home page or not. Add this condition wherever u are displaying the content. If you are using widget the probably u need to write this condition while calling sidebar.

```
if ( is_home() ) {
    // Hide Prices and products
} else {
    // Show prices and products.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', function( $price ) {

    if (is_front_page() || is_home()) {
        return '';
    }

    return $price;

});
```